# How to convert a generic dictionary into its known type?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

Using reflection, I am trying to grasp onto a class fields and populate them. Currently I have it detecting an instance of a `Dictionary<,>` and creating a `Dictionary<object,object>` to fill. Afterwards its tries to change the type, however this does not work and fails casting:

```
// Looping through properties. Info is this isntance.
// Check is a dictionary field.
Dictionary<object, object> newDictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();

// Populating the dictionary here from file.
Type[] args = info.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
info.GetSetMethod().Invoke(data, new object[]
    {
        newDictionary.ToDictionary(k => Convert.ChangeType(k.Key, args[0]),
                                   k => Convert.ChangeType(k.Value, args[1]))
    });
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should create generic instance of a dictionary that you found, you can't use yours one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create dictionary  manualy of type you found.

```
Type dictionary = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
Type[] typeArgs = info.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

// Construct the type Dictionary<T1, T2>.
Type constructed = dictionary.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
IDictionary newDictionary = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);

// Populating the dictionary here from file. insert only typed values below
newDictionary.Add(new object(), new object());


info.SetValue(data, newDictionary, null);
```

Proof for downvoters.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary<int, string> test = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var castedDictionary = (IDictionary)test;
        castedDictionary.Add(1, "hello");
        Console.Write(test.FirstOrDefault().Key);
        Console.Write(test.FirstOrDefault().Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IDictionary`, in my example Im creating instance of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`  (`Type dictionary = typeof(Dictionary<,>);`).

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary, ICollection, 
    IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable, ISerializable, 
    IDeserializationCallback
```

Comment: If you create the dictionary this way, then how to you populate it? Call the appropriate "Add" method via reflection?

Comment: simple newDictionary.Add(new object(),new object()); you can cast value to its type.

Comment: Wrong answer! `IDictionary<T,U>` does not inherit from `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late , but I had exactly this problem. user854301 was absolutely right.
I needed it to pass a generic dictionary at runtime, I had figured out most of it , just missing IDictionary. It did not work at the first time, cause I made the same mistake as Fyodor Soikin ; looking for `IDictionary<T,U>`.
However, the magic was in `System.Collections.IDictionary` and not `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<>`

```
Type[] types = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
Type dictType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(types);
IDictionary dict = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(dictType);
types.Dump();
dictType.GetGenericArguments().Dump();
dict.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Dump();
array.Split(';').ForEach(a =>
{
    dict.Add(MyFunctions.ChangeType(a.Split(',')[0], types[0]), MyFunctions.ChangeType(a.Split(',')[1], types[1]));
}); // List Items
dict.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Dump();
prop.SetValue(newT, dict);
```

Comment: So are you asking more here or adding on to someone else's answer?

Comment: Just to clarify an obvious confusion for me and might be for others.

Answer (score -1):

Create a helper generic class that would do whatever you need to do and produce a correctly typed result. Then instantiate that class dynamically based on the types known at runtime.

```
interface IHelper
{
    object CreateDictionary ();
}

class Helper<TKey, TValue> : IHelper
{
    public object CreateDictionary ()
    {
        return (whatever).ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>( blah );
    } 
}

var h = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( Helper<,> ).MakeGenericType( yourKnownKeyType, yourKnownValueType ) ) as IHelper;
info.SetValue( h.CreateDictionary() );
```

If this happens very often, you should also cache helper instances to avoid the impact of dynamic instantiation every time.